# Why do I have an 'failed to initiate app' error because of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dependency-injection, error-handling, angular-ui-router

I am using angular and I am getting the failed to initiate app error as it seems because of my jQuery script. I have no idea what is causing it. I included script tags for angular, jQuery, ui-router and materialize (which Im using) and injected them as my dependencies. Ive been looking at so many posts etc and just don't know what causes the error. Any ideas would be great. Thank you.

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)

project1/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js">    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   <script src="js/navbar/navbar.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <header></header>

    <navbar></navbar>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

</html>
```

project1/js/app.js

```
'use strict';
var app=angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.materialize']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`

but don't have

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-materialize/0.2.1/angular-materialize.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Just check you have all the dependencies required. For materialize I used 2 libs. I see only 1 in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-materialize/0.2.1/angular-materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps..